# Powershell Script failing to upsert to Salesforce

Tags: java, powershell, salesforce

I've been given the unenviable task of updating someone else's 4 year old half-finished code in a language that I largely don't know.

Previously, a powershell script uploaded all records from Microsoft Access to Salesforce, which required juggling of various config files. This would be done once a month.

I have changed it to upload all records from the previous two days, and scheduled it to run once a day. Now it only uploads some of the data (the difference varies by 60-100 values depending on the table).

I am currently painstakingly comparing the values manually to see if anything is common with the Microsoft Access data and salesforce data.

This is the bit that does the uploading:

```
CMD /c "call ..\Java\bin\java.exe -Xms1024m -Xmx1256m -cp ..\dataloader-28.0.2-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=.\config com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner process.name=Patients"
```

This bit is the bit that extracts Access data to csv:

```
 Get-AccessData -sql "select * from $tables where DateReceived >= `#$firstDate`#" -connection $db | Export-Csv -Path $outcsv –notype
```

Also, the script doesn't work if I run it through the Powershell editor, but does work if I just run it through the batch file my predecessor has kindly left.

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work," further.  What happens?  What's the error you receive, or the behavior that does occur?

Comment: A number of records will be added that say something "a009000002aECZy" instead of a name and $0, and some records will not be uploaded (presumably some of those are corrupted records somehow).


In the powershell editor, the script just stumbles at opening the database

`Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local 
machine."`


But it works fine in the regular shell. All the following errors are in relation to Powershell thinking that it can't access Access.


Really though, the first problem is my main one.

Comment: Alas, I tried to put in line breaks, but I ran out of time.